# How can I set a condition for a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a program that will read a JSON file and take the information I need from it. In my JSON file there is a parameter: `'exchangeId'` which outputs the exchange number. I would like to make sure that only those exchanges that I set, or rather their `'exchangeId'`, are recorded in my dictionary, and if coin don't have any `'exchangeId'` at the list this coin don't wanna save as JSON file. How can I do this?

My code:

```
response = s.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
json_data = response['data']
pairs = []
out_object = {}

for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
    pairs.append({
        "exchange_name": pair["exchangeName"],
        "market_url": pair["marketUrl"],
        "price": pair["price"],
        "last_update" : pair["lastUpdated"],
        "exchange_id": pair["exchangeId"] # That ids what I'm would to have
                                          # 102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400
        })

out_object["name_of_coin"] = json_data["name"]
out_object["marketPairs"] = pairs
out_object["pairs"] = json_data["numMarketPairs"]
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "name_of_coin": "yearn.finance",
    "marketPairs": [
        {
            "exchange_name": "Binance",
            "market_url": "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/YFI_USDT",
            "price": 24087.947333328204,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 270
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "FTX",
            "market_url": "https://ftx.com/trade/YFI/USD",
            "price": 24110.0,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 524
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Coinbase Exchange",
            "market_url": "https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/YFI-USD",
            "price": 24085.37,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:48:57.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 89
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
            "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/yfi_usdt",
            "price": 24096.582498139305,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 102
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bybit",
            "market_url": "https://www.bybit.com/en-US/trade/spot/YFI/USDT",
            "price": 24045.551976080656,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:48:10.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 521
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "FTX",
            "market_url": "https://ftx.com/trade/YFI/USDT",
            "price": 24079.402222379562,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 524
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Binance",
            "market_url": "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/YFI_BTC",
            "price": 24090.344540422568,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 270
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bithumb",
            "market_url": "https://www.bithumb.com/trade/order/YFI_KRW",
            "price": 25285.64198822739,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 200
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Gemini",
            "market_url": "https://gemini.com/",
            "price": 24088.85,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:55.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 151
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bitfinex",
            "market_url": "https://www.bitfinex.com/t/YFI:USD",
            "price": 24117.0,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 37
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Binance",
            "market_url": "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/YFI_BUSD",
            "price": 24061.58763433993,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 270
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Coinbase Exchange",
            "market_url": "https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/YFI-BTC",
            "price": 24020.347144833217,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:48:57.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 89
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "FTX US",
            "market_url": "https://ftx.us/trade/YFI/USD",
            "price": 23985.0,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:48:07.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 1177
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Binance",
            "market_url": "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/YFI_EUR",
            "price": 24018.992856877743,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 270
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bitfinex",
            "market_url": "https://www.bitfinex.com/t/YFI:UST",
            "price": 24036.37648809482,
            "last_update": "2021-12-07T17:49:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 37
        }
     }
]
```

Comment: Use a simple if condition to check if its a valid exchangeid, while looping through your JSON objects?

Comment: You should post the *input* JSON data not your current *output* JSON data to reproduce the issue.  Ideally make your sample code a [mcve] and *read* that input data and process it, instead of posting non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get information for the exchanges ids you want, just check for them when creating the `pairs` list. Since the ids are hashable, the fastest way to do that in Python is by storing the ids in a `set` which makes checking for membership extremely fast.

```
pairs = []
desired_ids = {102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400}  # Exchange ids

for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
    if pair["exchangeId"] in desired_ids:
        pairs.append({
            "exchange_name": pair["exchangeName"],
            "market_url": pair["marketUrl"],
            "price": pair["price"],
            "last_update" : pair["lastUpdated"],
            "exchange_id": pair["exchangeId"]
            })
```

##### Suggestion

You could simplify the conversion process and make it more "data-driven" by using a dictionary display (or [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) as they are more commonly called) to create the ones with renamed keys that get appended to the `pairs` list.

```
pairs = []
desired_ids = {102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400}  # Exchange ids
oldkeys = 'exchangeName', 'marketUrl', 'price', 'lastUpdated', 'exchangeId'
newkeys = 'exchange_name', 'market_url', 'price', 'last_update', 'exchange_id'

for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
    if pair["exchangeId"] in desired_ids:
        pairs.append({newkey: pair[oldkey] for oldkey, newkey in zip(oldkeys, newkeys)})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
exchanges = [102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400]

for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
    #Condition like Ronald Das Mentioned 
    if pair["exchangeId"] in exchanges:
            pairs.append({
                "exchange_name": pair["exchangeName"],
                "market_url": pair["marketUrl"],
                "price": pair["price"],
                "last_update" : pair["lastUpdated"],
                "exchange_id": pair["exchangeId"] #That ids what I'm would to have 102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400
                                
             })
```